# Decorate Tables

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You have $r$ red, $g$ green and $b$ blue balloons. To decorate a single table for the banquet you need exactly three balloons. Three balloons attached to some table shouldn't have the same color. What maximum number $t$ of tables can be decorated if we know number of balloons of each color?

I know the answer will at least be $\min(r,g,b)$. Also we need to add tables with $2$ reds, $2$ blues or $2$ greens. I cannot think of the formula for it

Comment: Taken from http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/478/C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $r\geqslant b\geqslant g$. Then, if $r\geqslant 2(b+g)$, the answer is $b+g$ because the best you can do is to use two red balloons for each table.

Conversely, if $r<2b+2g$, then you can check by induction that the answer is the integer part of $(b+r+g)/3$.